# How to disable http2 in nginx

Tags: nginx, safari, http2

due to [this](https://openradar.appspot.com/26406397) Safari Issue with HTTP/2 and Form POSTS I wanted to disable serving one Webpage via HTTP/2. So I just removed the "http2" from the server_name directive in corresponding nginx server block.

```
server {
  listen x.x.x.x:443 ssl;
  server_name xxxx;
  [...]
}
```

But after I restarted NginX and opened the website in various browsers the HTTP/2 Protocol is still used...
What am I doing wrong?

My NginX version is 1.10.1

Greets Jan

Comment: Look for `http2` in other server blocks.

Comment: There are other server blocks with entabled htt2. Can't I disable it only for one server block?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Someone answered with the correct solution here, but the post disappeared...

You have to disable http2 for all server blocks on one IP Adress / Port. If there is one server block configured to enable http2 it is enabled for all server blocks on this IP.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I just tried that myself, you actually have to disable http2 in all virtual host to disable http2. This actually sucks...

Comment: This just got me crazy for a while and I have seen this after I solved.

Comment: got me crazy too,
had to disable http2 for all other vhosts before it points back to http1/1

Comment: This can't possibly be true because my server is serving http1.1 on the ip address and h2 on the domain.

Answer (score 6):

NGINX can't serve multiple protocol on 1 port. **Make it different port**.
Example : HTTP/2 on port 443

```
server {
  listen x.x.x.x:443 ssl http2;
  server_name xxxx;
  [...]
}
```

and then HTTP 1.1 on port 444

```
 server {
      listen x.x.x.x:444 ssl;
      server_name xxxx;
      [...]
    }
```

or if you wanna disable http/2 module, re-install NGINX without --with-http_v2_module

Comment: This can't possibly be true because my server is serving http1.1 on the ip address and h2 on the domain.